# Which command shows the "ON DELETE" reference_option of foreign key in Mysql?

Tags: mysql, command

I need to check "ON DELETE" reference_option of a foreign key, for example, Restrict or Set Null, Cascade... Using command line in Linux.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This gets you the information directly

```
SELECT CONSTRAINT_NAME, TABLE_NAME, REFERENCED_TABLE_NAME,DELETE_RULE
FROM information_schema.REFERENTIAL_CONSTRAINTS
WHERE CONSTRAINT_SCHEMA = '<schema/database>'
AND TABLE_NAME = '<table>';
```

But you can also use

```
SHOW CREATE TABLE `<yourtable>`;
```

But this shows all infomation for a table.